# Sed substitution with Apex character

Tags: regex, sed, apex

I'm trying to implement the following substitution

```
sed -i 's/$config['default_host'] = '';/$config['default_host'] = 'localhost';/' /etc/roundcube/config.inc.php
```

but it's not working.

What i want to do to is replace `$config['default_host'] = '';` with `$config['default_host'] = 'localhost';` inside the file `/etc/roundcube/config.inc.php`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape the special characters, because `sed` consider `$` as a end of the character in a line

```
sed "s/\$config\['default_host'\] = '';/\$config['default_host'] = 'localhost';/" fileName
```

Using Grouping concept

```
sed "s/\(\$config\['default_host'\] = \)'';/\1'localhost';/" fileName
```

**Output:**

```
$config['default_host'] =  'localhost';
```